# Azure Search - Conditional Field Mapping

Tags: indexing, mapping, multilingual, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

So here is my problem.
I'm building an index with as data source a blob storage full of documents (docx, pptx, txt, pdf)
These documents are in different languages (2 to be exact, Dutch (nl) & English (en)).

To detect the language I make use of one of the build in skill set which returns me a new output with the language code.

What I want to do is that the text of the document is mapped to a field depending on the language. 
So if the document contains English text then it needs to go to the field [text_en] if Dutch then it needs to be mapped to the [text_nl] field.

How can I do this?
Anyone a clue?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No standard solution. I have build an Azure Function that I call as a custom skill that does the split for me. Probably not the most performant solution, because of data transfer, but it does the thing.

Comment: We just went for an approach of multiple indexers which achieves this. You can map the source field (text) to (text_en) or (text_nl). 

If you place your blobs in separate folders for EN and NL you can have an indexer for each folder which places it in the correct field of the Index. 
.... 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings

Comment: @TheDream Could indeed be a solution, but then you have needed to split your files in 2 folders already. What is not the case, the end-user on my end is just putting files in a folder not caring about anything.

Comment: The only way to do this is to use a custom skill. You can add your suggestion here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of April 2019, Azure added a new built-in skill called '[Conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-conditional)'.

It allows you to specify a boolean condition (e.g. "= $(/document/language) == 'nl'") and return a value based on the result, either static or linked to a node of the document tree.

For your case it would look something like this,

```
{
"@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Util.ConditionalSkill",
"context": "/document",
"inputs": [
    { "name": "condition", "source": "= $(/document/language) == 'nl'" },
    { "name": "whenTrue", "source": "/document/content" },
    { "name": "whenFalse", "source": "= null" }
],
"outputs": [ { "name": "output", "targetName": "text_nl" } ]
}
```

You would need to define one Conditional skill per language.